# 429 Rate exceeded responses for no apparent reason

Tags: google-cloud-run

We're using Contentful to manage CMS content. When you save content in Contentful it sends webhooks for a service we've set up on Cloud Run, which in turn ensures the updated content is built and deployed.

This setup has been previously so that the Cloud Run service was limited to 1 container max, with 80 concurrent requests limit. This should be plenty for the few webhooks we get occasionally.

Now when debugging complaints about content not being updated I bumped into a very persistent and irritating issue - Google Cloud Run does not try to process the 2 webhooks sent by Contentful, but instead responds to one of the 2 with status `429` and `Rate exceeded.` in response body.

This response does not come from our backend, I can see in the Cloud Run `Logs` tab the message generated by Google: `The request was aborted because there was no available instance.`

I've tried:

- Increasing number of processes on the container from 1 to 2 - should not be necessary due to use of an async framework
- Increasing number of containers from 1 to 2

The issue persists for the webhooks from Contentful.

If I try making requests from my local machine with `hey` that defaults to 200 requests with 50 concurrency, they all go through without any `429` status codes returned.

What is going on that generates `429` status codes when a *specific client* - in this case Contentful - makes ONLY 2 requests in quick succession? How do we disable or bypass this behavior?

`gcloud run services describe <name>` gives me these details of the deployment:

```
+ Service [redacted] in region europe-north1

URL:     https://[redacted].a.run.app
Ingress: all
Traffic:
  100% LATEST (currently [redacted])

Last updated on 2021-01-19T13:48:46.172388Z by [redacted]:
  Revision [redacted]
  Image:            eu.gcr.io/[redacted]/[redacted]:c0a2e7a6-56d5-4f6f-b241-1dd9ed96dd30
  Port:             8080
  Memory:           256Mi
  CPU:              1000m
  Service account:  [redacted]-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com
  Env vars:
    WEB_CONCURRENCY 2
  Concurrency:      80
  Max Instances:    2
  Timeout:          300s
```

Comment: Can you share the result of the command `gcloud run services describe ....`? And hide the URL and other sensitive information.

Comment: Could you share the whole cloud run configurations?

Comment: Added the details @guillaumeblaquiere

Comment: Nothing strange....Did you test in another region?

Comment: No, I have an existing service which is misbehaving, I need it to work.

Comment: I have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is more a speculation that an answer, but I would try re-deploying you Cloud Run service with `min-instances` set to `1` (or more).

Here is why.

In the [Cloud Run troubleshooting docs](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting#429-max-instances) they write (emphasis mine):

> This error can also be caused by a **sudden increase in traffic**, a long container startup time or a long request processing time.

Your Cloud Run service receives webhook events from a CMS (Contentful). And, as you wrote, these updates are rather sporadic. So I think that your situation could be the same as the one described in [this comment on Medium](https://dustindeus.medium.com/its-not-that-easy-5368b69d91c9):

> I tested “max-instances: 2” and the conclusion is I got 429 — Rate exceeded responses from Google frontend proxy because no container was running. It seems that a very low count of instances will deregister your service completely from the load-balancer until a second request was made.

If Google Cloud did indeed de-register your Cloud Run service completely because it was not receiving any traffic, re-deploying the service with at least one container instance could fix your issue. Another way would be to call your Cloud Run service every once in a while just to keep it "warm".

Comment: I wouldn't say going from 0 to 1/2 requests is a "sudden increase in traffic". Google Cloud Run normally handles that fine when you have a service that has been put to sleep and you point your browser to the service address. What GCR is expected to do is delay the responses by the few seconds that it takes to boot up the service again.

Comment: Have you somehow resolved the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I've just been battling with this issue when using websockets with CloudRun.
Specifically for me I'm connecting using the same device with two websockets. This is necessary for one to replace the other (because otherwise they'll time out). I am attempting to kill the existing connection from within the replacement connections handler.

The manifestation is as you've described, random 429s when running with a single server.

Things I tried which didn't work:

- Adding a random string to the path such as a connection ID.
- Increasing the minimum servers to 1.
- Increasing concurrency.
- Changing the frequency of my replacement connection.

Things that kind of worked:

- Increasing the min/max instances to 2. This failed periodically but was better.

Things that worked:

- Kill the websocket before connecting a new one. I tried doing this by locally killing the websocket on the client.
- Kill via an HTTP request before the replacement websocket is connected (preferable for my application).

I believe from all my testing that the issue lies with the websocket upgrade. It seems that Google Cloud detects the 101 upgrade while the existing socket is still connected and stops it.

The final solution which works for me is to kill the websocket within the handler, wait for the kill to propagate (about 200ms to be safe) and then upgrade the replacement websocket.

My assumption about the behaviour is Google Cloud limits concurrent connections from a single user to the number of available servers as a primitive load management strategy.

Hope this helps your situation!